# How to make a radiobutton in gridview checked based on a column value of database

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, radio-button

I have used gridview in my aspx page.. In that i have a five radio buttons in a single cell aligned horizontally.

```
<asp:GridView ID="CrowdRatingGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4" OnPageIndexChanging="CrowdRatingGrid_PageIndexChanging" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

<PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" PageButtonCount="4" />
<Columns>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="idea_id" HeaderText="Idea ID"></asp:BoundField>

  <asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderTemplate>
    Rating<br />1 2 3 4 5
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="rating" ID="1" />

                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="rating" ID="2" />

                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="rating" ID="3" />

                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="rating" ID="4" />

                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="rating" ID="5" />
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is my database table structure:

```
idea_id   rating_id
23882     3
23883     5
63720     1
```

This is my codebehind code for binding the gridview data:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindCrowdRatingGrid();
        }
    }
    private void BindCrowdRatingGrid()
    {

        Campaigns campaign = new Campaigns();
         ObjectResult<GetCrowdRating_Result> resultList = campaign.GetCrowdRatingIdeas();

        CrowdRatingGrid.DataSource = resultList;
        CrowdRatingGrid.DataBind();

    }
```

I am getting the "idea_id" value displayed correctly in the grid under header "Idea ID"
Also i need the radiobutton to be checked based on the value of rating_id.. If rating_id is 3 i need the radiobutton under 3 to be checked if 1 the radiobutton under 1 to be cheked..

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put RadioButtonList into ItemTemplate instead:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server' ID="Rating" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("rating_id") %>' RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="5" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

To remove text from each radiobutton set empty `Text` proprty for each ListItem. For hiding `ListItem` with  0 value you can set `RepeatLayout="Flow"` on RadioButtonList and set some CssClass property value like this: `CssClass="rating"`. Then add onto a page this style rule:

```
.rating > input:first-child
{
    display: none;
}
```

Also as an another option available you can use `SelectedIndex`  property of the RadioButtonList instead of SelectedValue and decrement each `rating_id` in resultList before binding to 1. This way you don't need surrogate ListItem with 0 value.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned but i am getting the following exception:

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Rating' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value]

Comment: execute this script against database and check which rating values you have: `select distinct rating_id from TABLENAME`

Comment: Done.. rating values are 3 1 2 4 5

Comment: Do you have null or 0 rating_id in `resultList`?

Comment: Ya i have 0 as value for some entries in resultlist

Comment: I have included another listitem <asp:ListItem Value="0" />... This solved my probs... But I don't want the radiobutton with value 0 to be displayed in the screen... Is it possible to hide that alone?

Comment: And am getting values near each radiobutton.. I don't need that as i have included that in header... Is it possible to hide that also?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Gave me an exact solution..:)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a RadioButtonList.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="myList" runat="Server">
   <asp:ListItem id="1" value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem id="2" value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem id="3" value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem id="4" value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem id="5" value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And then using something like this from your code behind:

```
myList.Items.FindByValue(yourDBValue).Selected = true;
```

Edit:

Or, bind the selectedValue in the control itself; as Yuriy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

GridView control has `RowCreated` event. There you can make the radio button checked based on the value from the database. You would probably have to use `FindControl()` to get the correct radio button.

This page has a good example of how to create `OnRowCreated` event handler:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to do a .FindControl by a string name, that is, if you are looking for your radio button inside the gridView. Just bind the grid view to your data source and then on the rowDataBound search for your radio button on every row. Lets say you have the 5 radio buttons with names:
rb1, rb2, rb3 and so on..
so when you get the rating id just add it to the string name like so

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)e.item;
   ..YourObject.. data = (..YourObject..)e.item.DataItem;
   //and now you search for your radio button
   RadioButton button = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rb" + data.rating_id); 
   //or just use the id as a name like you have allready named them
   button.cheched = true;
}
```

Comment: am getting [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] in the line 

RadioButton button = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rb" + data.rating_id);